# POSTing form data via Angular to a Flask web application and returning newly rendered template

Tags: angularjs, flask

i have the following AngularJS, HTML and Flask code.  i am able to select from a dropdown, and submit the value to the web server.  the web server is printing the selection, but i am wondering how to return the newly rendered template **report_filter.html** with the provided **serial_no** value.  i am displaying this value elsewhere in the page.  the post request is getting sent, but the new page is not rendering.  how should this intention be accomplished?  thanks!

**HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="printReport(selectedDevice)" name="deviceSelectionForm" novalidate>
    <legend>Select Device</legend>
    <label for="device_selection">serial number</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedDevice" class="form-control" id="device_selection" ng-options="DeviceSerialNo.device_id for DeviceSerialNo in DeviceSerialNos"></select>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="deviceSelectionForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**AngularJS**

```
var dlrApp = angular.module('dlrApp', []);

dlrApp.controller('MainCtrl',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.DeviceSerialNos = [
            {% for device_id in device_id_rows %}
                {device_id: "{{device_id}}"},
            {% endfor %}
        ];

        $scope.selectedDevice = {};

        $scope.printReport = function(filterParams) {
            $http.post("dataset", JSON.stringify(filterParams), null)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, filterConfig)
            {
                $scope['id'] = data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, filterConfig)
            {
                $scope['id'] = "SUBMIT ERROR";
            });
        }
    }
);
```

**Flask**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/dataset', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def report_filter():
    device_id_rows = [800, 801, 802, 803, 804]
    json_data = request.get_json()

    if json_data is not None and "device_id" in json_data:
        serial_no = json_data["device_id"].__str__()
    else:
        serial_no = "unknown"

    print serial_no
    return render_template('report_filter.html', device_id_rows=device_id_rows, serial_no=serial_no)
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error from Flask?  If so, please update the question with a stacktrace.

Comment: I do not see an error in my browser Dev window, nor on the server.  The browser simply never updates with the newly populated template.

Comment: Can you include your template?  The `report_filter.html`?

Comment: nothing in code shown would update any template in UI. Where is `$scope['id']` used? Also your `$http` config doesn't indicate expected html response. Why wouldn't you just return json data and let angular do the rendering based on data model in controller?

Comment: @charlietfl, (1) $scope['id'] is not used.  it was left over.  (2) how can i use config to indicate the expected HTML response?  (3) this last suggestion is one that sounds best.  how does JSON data get returned to the Angular data model?  this seems like the option that best regards Angular's intended pattern.  as you can probably tell, i am new to Angular, so any examples and focused guidance are incredibly appreciated.  thanks for the insight you've provided thus far in your comment!

Comment: Suggest you study some basic angular tutorials. They will all include using json data and template rendering based on data retrieved using `$http`. Just think of your back end as nothing but a data API.

Comment: i've looked into this some more, and have one question.  the user will submit an id (a string) to the server.  the server will then query for some data and prepare a report (JSON data) to a url.  Angular gets this data with an $http.get call.  i can't put this $http.get call in the $http.post success block since the report might not have submitted the data by the time this call is made.  so, how do i have $http.get wait for or detect the newly available data at the location provided to get?